# Pages module affect use of category url indicator?

Tags: switchee, pages

Putting together a blog template, using switchee to create all the related templates within the one.  I have 'Yes' selected for 'Use Category URL Titles In Links' and category is my reserve word.

My variable for switchee is {segment_2}.
my first case value is the following:

```
{case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''|category"}
```

my default case also has a value of 'article', see below:

```
{case value="article" default="Yes"}
```

The first case is to show the blog index, pagination and the category listing.  Second is for single entry.  I've used this numerous times before with no issue, but when placing this in this recent site the category value will not work.

I've even pulled this out of the first case above and placed in its own, see below:

```
{case value="category"} test {/case}
```

This doesnt work either.  But if I change the category url indicator reserve word from 'category' to 'topic' it works just as it should.

Again only thing I can assume is the Pages module is affecting it some how but really not sure as I don't think this would be an issue.

If not Pages, anything else possibly the issue?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Have you searched through any of your URL titles and see if the word /category/ is in there to narrow down whether it's a "Pages" issue?